# Firebird - serial field as in PGSQL?

Tags: sql, firebird, identity, identifier, auto-increment

PGSQL supports "serial" field type, which is converted to:

```
colname integer DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq') NOT NULL
```

This makes the identifier generating very easy.

In the Firebird I saw only trigger based solutions.

Is it possible to use same solution in Firebird for avoid the trigger creation for each table?

```
colname integer DEFAULT gen_id(generator, 1)
```

I don't have installed Firebird version now to check it, but maybe somebody knows the answer.

Or can I use "my function" for this?
Pseudo:

```
create function mygenid(genname) returns integer
begin
   return gen_id(genname);
end;

create table x(
   colname integer DEFAULT mygenid(generator, 1)
```

Comment: Why you want to avoid triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird 2.5 and earlier only support triggers for generating ids. Firebird 3.0 introduced an option to specify it in the table DDL with [`generated by default as identity`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-ddl-identity):

```
create table objects (
   id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
   name varchar(15)
);
```

This is syntactic sugar that will create the trigger and associated sequence for you.

In addition, Firebird 4.0 introduced [`generated always as identity`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-identity), which will - by default - not allow you to insert your own values, unless you're using the [`overriding system value`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-insert-overriding) clause.